Ansible Inventory Issue: UNREACHABLE Host Due to SSH Hostname Resolution Failure
I'm encountering an issue with my Ansible playbook when attempting to run it against a group of hosts defined in my inventory. Despite being able to SSH into the servers directly, when I run my playbook, I get an error for the master group indicating that Ansible cannot resolve the hostname:
fatal: [master]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname master: nodename nor servname provided, or not known", "unreachable": true}

Here's my inventory.ini:
[all:vars]
ansible_user=root

[cluster]
master
worker

[master]
nuc1
nuc2

[worker]
CPU
GPU

[CPU]
server ...

[GPU]
server1 ...
server2 ...

[admin]
admin-pc ...

[nuc]
...

[thinksystem]
...


I have fixed the problem with the :children directive, which is used for defining groups within groups, as shown below:
[all:vars]
ansible_user=root

[cluster:children]
master
worker

[master]
nuc1
nuc2

[worker:children]
CPU
GPU

[CPU]
server ...

[GPU]
server1 ...
server2 ...

[admin]
admin-pc ...

[nuc]
...

[thinksystem]
...

